# Mongoose aggregate: how to create fields dynamically from the user request

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, aggregate, nest

Please someone help me! I can't find the solution in documentation or other topics.

I'm using mongodb aggregation in Mongoose/Nest.js project to return the document data with some formatting and filtering. I have the structure of the mongo document like

```
{
_id: '1',
outputs: [
  {
  fileName: 'fileName1',
  data: [
   {
     columnName1: 3,
     columnName2: 4,
     ........
     columnName30: 5
   },
   {
     columnName1: 1,
     columnName2: 2,
     ........
     columnName30: 3
   },
   ...........
  ]

 },
 {
  fileName: 'fileName1',
  data: [
   {
     columnName1: 3,
     columnName2: 4,
     ........
     columnName30: 5
   },
   {
     columnName1: 1,
     columnName2: 2,
     ........
     columnName30: 3
   },
   ...........
  ]
 }
........
]
}
```

I've already done some formatting, but now I need to include to the response only requested by the user fields (`columnNamesToChoose`). And filter their values depending on `gte, lte` of `mainColumnName`. Inside `$project` I was going to use some mapping like this, but it doesn't work. Could you please help me to fix this part of code?

```
...columnNamesToChoose.map((columnName) => ({ [columnName]: {
 $map: {
              input: {
                $filter: {
                  input: '$outputs.data',
                  as: 'item',
                  cond: {
                    $and: [
                      { $gte: [`$$item.${mainColumnName}`, gte] },
                      { $lte: [`$$item.${mainColumnName}`, lte] },
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
              as: 'file',
              in: `$$file.${columnName}`,
            },

} })),
```

This is the full code of aggregation:

```
mainColumnName = 'column1' (from the body of the user request)
columnNamesToChoose = ['column2', 'column5'] (from the body of the user request)
myModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { _id: Number(id) },
      },
      { $unwind: '$outputs' },
      {
        $match: { 'outputs.fileName': fileName },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: '$_id',
          fileName: '$outputs.fileName',
          [mainColumnName]: {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $filter: {
                  input: '$outputs.data',
                  as: 'item',
                  cond: {
                    $and: [
                      { $gte: [`$$item.${mainColumnName}`, gte] },
                      { $lte: [`$$item.${mainColumnName}`, lte] },
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
              as: 'file',
              in: `$$file.${mainColumnName}`,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ])
```

My result:

```
{
 "0": {
        "column2": [
            4,
            2,
            1,
            5
        ]
    },
    "1": {
        "column5": [
            1,
            8,
            9,
            0
        ]
    },
    "_id": 1,
    "fileName": "somefilename.txt",
    "column1": [
        3,
        1,
        2,
        20
    ],
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
"_id": 1,
        "fileName": "somefilename.txt",
        "column1": [
            3,
            1,
            2,
            20
        ],
        "column2": [
            4,
            2,
            1,
            5
        ],
        "column5": [
            1,
            8,
            9,
            0
        ],
}
```

Comment: @nimrodserok I've provided my and expected results to the description

Comment: There is no `column5` on your sample data. No `gte` and `lte` as well. I don't think the expected result match the sample data

Comment: I think that this approach for some reason trigger kind of autoformatting in aggregate, to show the array as key: value

Comment: @nimrodserok column5 exists, I just didn't show it in the list of columns, it is between column2 and column30, this range is marked with dots (......)
gte and lte are also provided by the user . Sorry I can't show the real data, so let's say that here gte = 1, lte = 20

Answer (score 0):

One option is to first `$reduce` and then `$unwind`, `$match` and `$group`, where the `$group` stage is built dynamically on the code (for-loop) according to the input:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: id}},
  {$project: {
      outputs: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$outputs",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {$cond: [
                  {$eq: ["$$this.fileName", fileName]},
                  "$$this.data",
                  []
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$outputs"},
  {$match: {"outputs.columnName1": {$gte: gte, $lte: lte}}},
  {$group: {
      _id: 0,
      column1: {$push: "$outputs.columnName1"},
      column2: {$push: "$outputs.columnName2"},
      column5: {$push: "$outputs.columnName5"}
  }},
  {$set: {fileName: fileName}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cagpde5fvnJ)

On js it will look something like:

```
const matchStage = {$match: {}};
matchStage.$match[`outputs.${mainColumnName}`] = {$gte: gte, $lte: lte};
const groupStage = {$group: {_id: 0}};
for (const col of columnNamesToChoose ) {
  groupStage.$group[col] = {$push: `"$outputs.${col}"`}
};
const aggregation = [
  {$match: {_id: id}},
  {$project: {
      outputs: {$reduce: {
          input: "$outputs",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {$cond: [
                  {$eq: ["$$this.fileName", fileName]},
                  "$$this.data",
                  []
              ]}
          ]}
      }}
  }},
  {$unwind: "$outputs"},
  matchStage,
  groupStage,
  {$set: {fileName: fileName}}
],
  
const res = await myModel.aggregate(aggregation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the most readable and useful answer for me, it's to use `$function` inside `$project` and get all the data I need in `args` using only js and no mongo syntax